# Istio how to achieve routing by url and then split traffic by header?

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

I have an istio-gateway to handle sourth-north trafic, and I created a virtualservice for that gateway to do the reverse proxy just like what nginx does, something like:

```yaml
host:
  - example.com # domain for my website
http:
  - match:
      - url:
          prefix: /a/
      - url:
          prefix: /b/c
    route:
      - destination:
          host: foo.ns.svc.cluster.local
          port: 8082
  - match:
      - url:
          prefix: /x
    route:
      - destination:
          host: bar.ns.svc.cluster.local
          port: 9952
  # and many other rules, just like nginx location directives
```

And then, I want to do grayscale upgrade for the foo svc. So I created a dr for that svc to define subsets and a vs for that svc to define the routing behavior. I want to achieve that all the traffic to foo.ns.svc.cluster.local can be split by header and then routed to different subsets.

```yaml
kind: DestinationRule
spec:
  host: 
    - foo.ns.svc.cluster.local 
  subsets:
    - labels:
        version: v1
      name: v1
    - labels:
        version: v1
      name: v2
```

```yaml
kind: VirtualService
spec:
  host: foo.ns.svc.cluster.local 
  http:
    - match:
        - headers:
            my-env:
              exact: v1
      route:
        - destination:
            host: foo.ns.svc.cluster.local
            subset: v1
    - match:
        - headers:
            my-env:
              exact: v2
      route:
        - destination:
            host: foo.ns.svc.cluster.local
            subset: v2
```

But this didn't work. Traffic in the mesh can go to desired subset, but traffic from outside of the cluster(which go through the gateway) go to random subset.
The reason why I created an individual vs for foo.ns.svc.cluster.local is that I want all the traffic can apply this routing rule no matter where it comes from(outside mesh or inside mesh).
Am I missing something, or how to achieve this?

didn't find any docs online for this

---

It works if I config the header match rules in gateway virtualservice, but for my cases, it's nearly impossible to do that. Because I have hundreds of url match rules in gw vs, just like location directives in nginx.conf. If I config header match for each url, if header match A and url is /a then go to subset v1 of foo svc, if header match B and url is /a then subset v2 of foo svc, else if url is /a then subset stable of foo svc ...
This means the number of HTTPRoutes in my gw vs will grow exponentially, thus no one can maintain it anymore## Heading ##